# Supertest + Restify gzipResponse file upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, supertest, superagent

I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

when attempting to upload a file using supertest to a simple restify server, with `gzipResponse` turned on.

Versions etc:

```
$ npm list | grep 'super\|mocha\|restify'
├─┬ mocha@2.4.5
├─┬ restify@4.0.4
└─┬ supertest@1.2.0
  └─┬ superagent@1.8.3

$ node -v
v5.5.0
```

The server:

```
const restify = require('restify');
const server = restify.createServer();

server.use(restify.gzipResponse());

server.put('image', (req, res) => {
    res.send(200);
});

module.exports = server;
```

The test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('./index');
const path = require('path');

describe('insertImage', function () {

    it('should send an image', done => {
        request(server)
            .put('/image')
            .attach('image', path.join(__dirname, 'pc.png'))
            .expect(200, done);
    });

});
```

The test will pass when `gzipResponse` is disabled, and it will also pass if no file is attached.

I'm not sure whether this issue is superagent/supertest related, or whether the problem lies with restify/gzip. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a server config issue with your project. I think [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) and [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) handle gzip responses just fine.

Here is a mocha test snippet I wrote that shows it working. Granted this is using an express server but it still has gzip compression enabled.

```
var express = require('express');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.put('/image', function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

describe('Test gzip with file upload', function(){
  it('Get a test page', function(done) {
    supertest(app)
        .get('/test')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
        });
  });

  it('Upload an image', function(done) {
    supertest(app)
        .put('/image')
        .attach('image', path.join(__dirname, 'pc.png'))
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
        });
  });
});
```

Though I haven't used restify much I just created a quick sample that uses restify as the server and the tests with supertest still pass. In your example above do you need to add a server.listen call?

```
var supertest = require('supertest');
var restify = require('restify');
var path = require('path');

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.gzipResponse());

server.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200);
});
server.put('/image', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});



describe('Test gzip with file upload', function(){
  it('Get a test page', function(done) {
    supertest(server)
      .get('/test')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });

  it('Upload an image', function(done) {
    supertest(server)
      .put('/image')
      .attach('image', path.join(__dirname, 'neo.jpg'))
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah it's weird, I know. It really seems to be a problem with the specific restify + compression + supertest combo. Uploading a file using curl works perfectly...

Comment: @Edo I just updated the answer to show an example using restify as the API server. I am using the same deps including node 5.5. Do you need a server.listen call?

Comment: Running your tests fails for me because it seems that you've forgotten the `done` arguments, in your `it` tests. I added the done argument, and ran your tests, with the `server.listen` call, but I still have the upload test failing. Very strange.

Comment: Man, that's really weird. I fixed the examples with the missing done parameters. Not sure why that example is still not working for you.